# cudnn path shows 7.0.5.15 but the system only recognizes cudnn 7102

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, gpu

I am trying to run a bit of python code that uses `tensorflow-gpu`. However, when the process tries to run, I'm getting the following error:

> 2018-04-13 20:03:49.215876: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:396] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7102 (compatibility version 7100) but source was compiled with 7005 (compatibility version 7000).  If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible version specified during compile configuration.
>
> 2018-04-13 20:03:49.220783: F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:712] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms)

However, I typed `env` and it listed `CUDNN_VERSION=7.0.5.15` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64`

I installed cudnn 7.0.5 by downloading and copying the relevant files into `/user/local/cuda/`

Why is this error occurring? I am using a kubernetes backed cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767269/how-can-i-install-cudnn-on-ubuntu-16-04/767270#767270) from **askubuntu**

Pasting the instructions from that post here:

Step 0: Install cuda from the standard repositories. (See [How can I install CUDA on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/799184/10425))

Step 1: Register an nvidia developer account and [download cudnn here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) (about 80 MB)

Step 2: Check where your cuda installation is. For the installation from the repository it is `/usr/lib/...` and `/usr/include`. Otherwise, it will be `/usr/local/cuda/` or `/usr/local/cuda-<version>`. You can check it with `which nvcc` or `ldconfig -p | grep cuda`

Step 3: Copy the files:

```
$ cd folder/extracted/contents
$ sudo cp -P include/cudnn.h /usr/include
$ sudo cp -P lib64/libcudnn* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn*
```

Basically, on the `cudnn` installation instruction, it only tells you to copy your `cudnn.h` and `libcudnn*` files to the `cuda` folder. However, in addition to that, one also needs to copy those files inside the systems main `include` and `lib64` folders. That will fix this problem.